# Time-tracking app with automatic classification

Tags: time-management, machine-learning

I'm looking for a time-tracking app with automatic classification. In most time-tracking apps, I have to tell the app that what I'm doing (i.e. task) and where the task should linked to (e.g. project, client, tag).

However, I'm wondering that it could be possible by using machine learning or something, to classify the tracking data automatically. (Such an app may log an application, the title of the window, URL of the website, connected Wi-Fi SSID, location, time, or whatever it can get.)

As far as I know, in accounting (bookkeeping/journaling), there are a couple of software/services available in the market that process the input (credit card statement, bank statement, receipt, etc.) and classify them into an appropriate account title automatically. Some of them require users to classify them manually at the beginning, but apps "learn" it.

So, my question is, is there any time-tracking app that implements those functions?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this question while searching, but also found this:

https://timelyapp.com

There's an "AI" function to determine what you worked on based on data from [integrations with various apps](https://timelyapp.com/apps-and-integrations/), and also a native app that runs in the background. There's a long waiting list for the feature, but it looks pretty good from the outside.

Comment: And also with [Trello integration](https://timelyapp.com/apps-and-integrations/trello/)

Answer (score 1):

[ActivityWatch](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch) allows regex-based classification of activities.